# Can you give me a good example of using a predicate that does not involve a collection, list, enumerator or IEnumerable?

Tags: predicate

The title pretty much asks what I want -- an example of using predicates that **don't** involve iterating over a collection, using IEnumerable, or anything like that.

I don't care what language you use, or even if you provide a code example.  I'd be grateful if you only described a simple example which illustrates predicates without the usual uses.

I'm working on an article and I'm stumped, so any examples will be gratefully received and credited.

Comment: Your question depends somewhat on the semantics of "predicate." Do you mean "any function of one argument which returns a Boolean," or "'predicate' as used in predicate logic?" The latter strongly implies / demands the domain of sets; the former does not.

Comment: @CraigStuntz --  I'm talking the former.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one project I have manually implemented cache dependencies using predicates.

Whenever a new item is put in the cache that depends on another cached item, a predicate delegate is created which will check whether the dependency is still valid or whether the cached item has to be invalidated.

Whenever a cached item was accessed, and it had a dependency check predicate assigned, then it was checked before the cached item was returned.

If course that probably could be solved without using predicates, but that solution was pretty elegant and enabled implementing the cache dependencies by easily injecting the depency checking method.

Comment: This is a good example of why it often makes sense to inject functions rather than instances. On the other hand, there's really nothing special about a predicate in this case. Other function types might do for very similar cases.

Comment: Yes. In more functional programming languages this is the default way to solve problems. I do this in JavaScript all the time.